# EE Addon Module - How to store a value in a EE session?

Tags: cache

I am needing to set and and retrieve a variable within this addon.
For example on one page my module connects to a remote server and gets an auth code. I would then use that auth code for all subsequent requests back to that remote server.

I assumed that like in codeigniter i could just store this in a session, most likely the EE session. But everything i have tried does not store for the period of the session, just the time it is set.

Am i being a numpty?
Or do i need to roll my own session setup and storage?

Thanks, N

Answer (score 2):

I think I would use the cache vs. the user data. The userdata is tied to the specific member that is logged in. The session cache is more appropriately used for add-ons (or developers) wanting to retrieve information in a subsequent method call.

```
$this->EE->session->set_cache('your_addon', 'your_cache_var', 'some value');

$cache = $this->EE->session->cache['your_addon']['your_cache_var']' // return 'some value'
```

Comment: Yes, Justin is correct. It would be better way.

Comment: $this->EE->session->set_cache('your_addon', 'your_cache_var', 'some value');

This works - but only for the current page request. It is not persistent data in the session, more like flash data in the session.

So i think this leaves only native PHP Sessions.
Thanks

Comment: If that is the case, I would use the system/expressionengine/cache directory. EE doesn't support PHP sessions natively, so I would avoid using them. Use the cache directory or set a cookie. Take a look at how CartThrob does it with their shopping cart. They use a combination of cookies and DB records.

Answer (score 0):

With the EE session class you can set user data like:

```
$this->EE->session->set_userdata(array('session_name' => $value));
```

to get this user session data:

```
$session_name = $this->EE->session->userdata('session_name');
```

It would be better to use global session variable $_SESSION.

like:

```
if (session_id() == "") 
{
session_start(); 
}

$_SESSION['SESSION_NAME'] = $value;
```

Comment: Yes i am currently using the native PHP method, but ideally wanted to store it within the native EE session. I am guessing you are saying you cannot. Thanks, N

Comment: as I mentioned you can store user session data. Please see my updated answer. I hope, it would work for you.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Session::set_userdata()

Comment: FYI ExpressionEngine 2.0 removed the set_userdata() function.  For a workaround, see here: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/138599/

Answer (score 0):

FYI ExpressionEngine 2.0 removed the set_userdata() function. For a workaround, [see this thread.](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/138599/)